# New to python, help please with reading this lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, arguments

```
square = {2: 4, -3: 9, -1: 1, -2: 4}
key1 = max(square)
print(key1) # 2
key2 = max(square, key = lambda k: square[k])
print(key2) # -3
key3 = square[key2]
print(key3) # 9
```

Q1: sorry if this question seems irrelevant but, how does square[k] works, I can't get the logic behind it every time I remove K, the answer would be the same as key1
Q2: How does the logic works with key3 resulting to 9

THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: The first `max` will return the largest *key*, the `max` with the `lambda` will return the key with the largest associated *value*.

Comment: how does square[k] works and key3 resulting to 9. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) is an ordering function that extracts the value to order by. Thus, `max(square, key = lambda k: square[k])` returns the key of `square` that has the greatest corresponding value.

Comment: thanks so, basically key3 is calling for the key of the value 9,  but how does square[k] in key2 works

Comment: @NewCoder `square[k]` obtains the value of the key `k` in `square`.

Comment: @NewCoder And `key2` is the key for the greatest value.

Comment: Thank you!, sorry if the question is kinda obvious. I'm just really overloaded with info right now!

Comment: @NewCoder Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, *k* is referring to the key in the dictionary *square*.

Dictionaries are made up of key:value pairs, which you can see in the declaration of *square* in the first line.

If we want a specific value from a dictionary, we need to reference it's key. So if we want to print *4* from our dictionary, we need to feed in the key *2*.

So the following code would print '4':

```
square = {2: 4, -3: 9, -1: 1, -2: 4}
k = 2
print(square[k])
```

Comment: Thankss! I kinda get the logic now. I'm gonna do something testing myself.